# Font awesome not loading when using Python simple http server

Tags: python, html, font-awesome, simplehttpserver

I have this simple html file that displays the thumbs down icon using font awesome.

```
<html>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.4.7/webfont.js"></script>
  <script>
    WebFont.load({
      custom: {
      families: ['FontAwesome'],
      urls : ['//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css']
    },
    fontloading: function(familyName, fvd) {},
    fontactive: function(familyName, fvd) {},
    fontinactive: function(familyName, fvd) {
    }});
  </script>
  <style type="text/css">
  html{
    background-color:black;
    color:green;
  }

  .thumb_down:before {
      content:"";
      font-family: FontAwesome;
      color: #ffffff;
  }

  </style>

  <body>
    <div class="thumb_down">I am here! </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/UhJ4g/1/)

Now when I try hosing this on my local machine using a Python SimpleHTTPServer, my font is not rendered properly. I get this output

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

[image: font_awesome_python]

But when I host the same using a php server, I get the correct result as shown in the fiddle.

```
php -S localhost:9000
```

Any idea if this is a limitation of a python Simple HTTP Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably the encoding. PHP is probably adding a header and python is not. If you add this after your `<html>` tag (like jsfiddle does) it will probably work

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"> 
</head>
```