# python simple HTTP server not loading font-awesome fonts

Tags: python, font-awesome, simplehttpserver

I'm trying to get simple HTTP server to load font-awesome but can get it to work, I only get small squares.

I believe it might be some kind of mime type issue.
The HTML page and font-awesome fonts load if the page is opened directly in the browser but not when loaded by simple HTTP server.

This question seemed the same but placing

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

in the HTML code didn't help me. 
[Font awesome not loading when using Python simple http server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22850959/font-awesome-not-loading-when-using-python-simple-http-server)

```
from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler,HTTPServer
from os import curdir, sep
import cgi

import subprocess as sub
import time

PORT_NUMBER = 8080


class myHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):


    def do_GET(self):
        if self.path=="/":
            self.path="/index.html"

        try:

            sendReply = False
            if self.path.endswith(".html"):
                mimetype='text/html'
                sendReply = True
            if self.path.endswith(".jpg"):
                mimetype='image/jpg'
                sendReply = True
            if self.path.endswith(".png"):
                mimetype='image/png'
                sendReply = True
            if self.path.endswith(".gif"):
                mimetype='image/gif'
                sendReply = True
            if self.path.endswith(".svg"):
                mimetype='image/svg+xml'
                sendReply = True
            if self.path.endswith(".css"):
                mimetype='text/css'
                sendReply = True
            if self.path.endswith(".js"):
                mimetype='application/javascript'
                sendReply = True
            if self.path.endswith(".ttf"):
                mimetype='application/x-font-ttf'
                sendReply = True
            if self.path.endswith(".otf"):
                mimetype='application/x-font-opentype'
                sendReply = True
            if self.path.endswith(".woff"):
                mimetype='application/font-woff'
                sendReply = True

            if sendReply == True:
                #Open the static file requested and send it
                f = open(curdir + sep + self.path, 'rb')
                self.send_response(200)
                self.send_header('Content-type',mimetype)
                self.end_headers()
                self.wfile.write(f.read())
                f.close()
                print(curdir + sep + self.path)
            return

        except IOError:
            self.send_error(404,'File Not Found: %s' % self.path)

    def do_POST(self):

        if self.path=="/run":
            form = cgi.FieldStorage(
                fp=self.rfile,
                headers=self.headers,
                environ={'REQUEST_METHOD':'POST',
                         'CONTENT_TYPE':self.headers['Content-Type'],
            })


                        #self.send_response(200)
                        #self.end_headers()
            return
```

This is part of the html page:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>HW Test</title>

        <!-- Bootstrap -->

        <link href = "css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
        <link href = "css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
        <link href = "css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>

        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>


<body>
    <div class = "container"> 
        <div class="row">
            <input id="box1" type="checkbox" />
            <label for="box1">Checkbox 1</label>
            <input id="box2" type="checkbox" />
            <label for="box2">Checkbox 2</label>
        </div>
...
```

The check boxes are shown as small squares, not check boxes.
These should be displayed by font-awesome that wont load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in font file names, for example, the last version of `font-awesome.css` contains:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.7.0');
  src: url('./fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0') ...
```

It means that `self.path` contains something like:

```
/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0
```

And checks like `if self.path.endswith(".woff")` would fail.